# How to click button using scroll on a specific DIV using Selenium with C#

Tags: c#, selenium, scroll

I need to click a 'Save' button that is at the bottom of a pop up window. 
First I wrote code to simply click the 'Save' button but I got exception "button is not clickable at point (869, 383)." Ok, I thought, I'll scroll to the bottom of the pop up window so the button is visible and can be clicked. I implemented code to scroll down to where the button is visible, but still the exception "button not clickable at point" comes up and the button is not clicked. Please help

Here is my code

```
//To scroll down to the bottom of pop up window
IJavaScriptExecutor down = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
down.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[1];", driver.FindElement(By.Id("move_In")), 1000);
 //Click Save button       
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[contains(.,'Save')]")).Click();
```

Here is the elements in webpage:

[image]

Comment: I guess there is a condition for button to be clickable. If yes, are you inserting wait time for the button to be clickable?

Comment: I added a 20 second implicit wait but still that stubborn button refuses to be clicked =(

Comment: can you share full exception you are getting?

Comment: OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: 'unknown error: Element <button type="button" class="btn btn-success ng-scope ng-isolate-scope" ng-if="commonItems.authorizedControls.LeadCenterEdit" click-and-disable="submit()">...</button> is not clickable at point (869, 383). Other element would receive the click: <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl">...</div>     What does "Other element would receive the click:" mean? that seems like a promising clue.

Comment: that means there may be other button element or another element is covering the element you are trying to click. You can either try to give absolute path to button element or use javascript executor. Please see my answer below.

Comment: @theGuy why absolute path is suggested? 
JavaScriptt click should not be suggested unless you know the overlay is permanent.

Comment: @Rajagopalan, I am sure I explained in my comment above. "that means there may be other button element" so absolute path to try to click the element. "or another element is covering the element you are trying to click." so javascript solution since she already applied 20 sec wait and it didn't helped. I hope this answered your question.

Comment: @theGuy Absolute path still won't work, try it. She is using implicit wait of 20 seconds that would wait until element exist so that doesn't matter here because it would still throw the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is how you can click on button using javascript in java, I am sure it is quite similar in C#

```
WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.id("someid"));
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", button);
```

Comment: I am glad I was able to help, please accept this answer

Comment: @Omw2daBeach hi you don't have to do JavaScript click if your overlaying element disappear in another few seconds, if your overlaying element is permanent then you can go with JavaScript click. Always relay on WebDriber click, not JavaScript click.